# How to solve "Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found"?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am doing a tutorial and am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found (LONG URL) on line 8

The code on line 8 is:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

I saw online someone said to see if it was turned on in my phpinfo(), but there wasn't anything listed in there under for "mysqli".

Also, I am running PHP version 5.2.5

Comment: You can use [a handwritten MYSQLi class](http://codecanyon.net/item/php-mysqli-to-mysql-converter-class/2826314), so you don't need to install mysqli. It's the only solution if you don't own the server.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305919/php-mysqli-works-in-command-line-but-not-on-pages

Comment: if you come from php storm -> https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207033955-mysqli-connect-mysql-connect-error- or https://web.archive.org/web/20200805054537/https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207033955-mysqli-connect-mysql-connect-error-

Comment: On PHP 7.4 at least the class name is lowercase `new mysqli()`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to [install MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).

Comment: On AWS, you just run [`sudo yum install php-mysqli`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23713997/111307)

Comment: For me it was fixed with: apt-get install php7.0-mysql.  I am running on Raspbian Stretch 9

Comment: On AWS with amazon linux, it would be something like `sudo yum install php56-mysqlnd.x86_64` (pick the one matching to which version of php you have installed)

Comment: I am using windows 10 and installed php using a zip folder. my php.int contains extension=mysqli . but I am still getting error undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: On Ubuntu, it’s not part of the distribution anymore. You can install it at any time with:   sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd

Answer (score 50):

You can check if the mysqli libraries are present by executing this code:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
```

Comment: I still get "We don't have mysqli!!!" even after running ` sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd` ?

Comment: I get the 'Phew we have it but I keep getting the same error that Class 'msqli' not found in... any ideas?

Comment: The OP wants a solution and not a checking if the error exists I think. So maybe you can improve your lines.

Answer (score 47):

If you are on Ubuntu, run:

```
 sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd
```

And don't forget to restart the php service after this (Apache or php-fpm depends on the setup).

Comment: And don't forget to restart Apache after this!

Comment: @fracz Restarting Apache is the part I forgot.  I only restarted MySQL.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not enough. I was still lacking php5-mysql package. Use `sudo` `apt-get -y install php5-mysql php5-mysqlnd` to get both.
Is it what you were missing, @Hermann Ingjaldsson ?

Comment: it was some configuration error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535173/enable-mysqli-in-my-in-webserver-copy-of-php

Comment: solved my problem, apt install mysqlnd
however, my php apps was working before...
and it stops with the error above.

Comment: what is the diff between `php-mysql` and `php-mysqlnd`?  Why do you need both?

Answer (score 38):

If you're calling "new mysqli(..)" from within a class that is namespaced, you might see a similar error `Fatal error: Class 'foo\bar\mysqli' not found in`. The way to fix this is to explicitly set it to the root namespace with a preceding backslash like so:

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new \MySQLi($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Answer (score 18):

In addition to uncommenting the *php_mysqli.dll* extension in *php.ini*, also uncomment the *extension_dir* directive in *php.ini* and specify your location:

```
extension_dir = "C:\software\php\dist\ext"
```

This made it work for me.

Comment: It worked for me but with `./ext` which is the relative path. And I had to rename `php.ini-development` to `php.ini` and uncomment in that file `extension=php_mysqli.dll`. Oh boy, I did not miss you PHP.

Comment: The trick here for me (on Windows) was to type in absolute path to extensions dir in "extension_dir".

Comment: The solution here is for Windows, not for other Os.

Answer (score 13):

If you are on Docker...

Inside php-container RUN:

```
#docker-php-ext-install mysqli

#apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 5):

My [OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) is [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29). I solved this problem by using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: On mint 19: sudo apt-get install php-mysql

Answer (score 3):

How to Enable mysqli in php.ini

1. Edit/uncomment by removing ';'(colon) the following config in php.ini:
   **1st** (uncomment and add config):

   ```
   include_path = "C:\php\includes"
   ```

   **2nd** (uncomment):

   ```
   extension_dir = "ext"
   ```

   **3rd** (uncomment and edit config):

   ```
   extension=C:/PHP/ext/php_mysql.dll
   extension=C:/PHP/ext/php_mysqli.dll
   ```
2. Restart the IIS server
3. Make sure that mysql is running on the system.

How to load php.ini file

1. Rename any one of the file php.ini-production/php.ini-development to php.ini from C:\PHP(note now the extention will be ini i.e "php.ini").
2. After renaming to php.ini file restart server
3. See the changes in http://localhost/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your PHP folder.
2. Find php.ini-development and open it.
3. Find `;extension=mysqli`
4. delete the `;` symbol
5. save file and change the file extension from php.ini-development to php.ini
6. Restart the server and test the code:

```
    if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {  
            echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';  
     } else {  
         echo 'mysqli is installed';
     }
```

7. if it not working, change both extension_dir in php.ini from "ext" to "c:\php\ext"
   and extension=mysqli to extension=php_mysqli.dll then test again
   **Remember to reset the server every time you test**

Answer (score 2):

Seems like problem with your installation.

- Have you installed MySQLi?
- Have you activated it in php.ini?
- Restarted Apache and/or PHP-FPM?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using docker, I ran into this issue, and resolved it by using my own Dockerfile instead of the php:fpm image:

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I might help anybody with the same problem using Namesco servers.
I have been trying to fix this problem after moving a database from my local server on home pc to namesco. They would not assist they said it was a coding issue.

- However, it was simple to fix from their CPANEl LINUX hosting
  interface.
- Click on php.
- then click on php modules and from their list of preinstalled modules just click the box for mysqli.
- Then click save. (No need to change code if it worked(s) on another server.)

Unfortunately, their support articles were a waste of time. After reading this I went to admin interface with a new determination.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP zip includes most of the commonly used extensions (*.dll on windows such as php_mysqli.dll) under the \ext directory, however they are not enabled by default. You might be getting this Fatal Error when trying to use MySQLi:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\myProject\ class.Database.php on line 24
```

To enable extensions, open php.ini (you might need to first copy php.ini-development as php.ini), and un-comment (or add) these two lines:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

And any particular extensions you are getting Fatal Errors for, i.e. for mysqli:

```
extension=mysqli
```

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh install of PHP, remove `;` before `extension_dir` in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is go to the `php.ini` file and on line 926 (depending on version) delete #. It should look like this:

```
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c
;extension=odbc
```

Save the file and open console (cmd) as administrator. Go to the path `Apache24 / bin` and enter `httpd -k restart`. This command will restart your server. After that, refresh the page and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Some distributions (such as [Gentoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux)) support multiple installations of PHP, and you have to make sure you're using one with mysqli installed and enabled.

On Gentoo, I had installed a new PHP (with the mysqli USE flag enabled), but I needed to activate the new version of PHP (since the old one must have been missing mysqli):

```
# eselect php list apache2
  [1]   php5.3 *
  [2]   php5.5
# eselect php set apache2 2
You have to run `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart' for the changes to take effect
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked all above and it didn't work for me,

There are some steps I found.

I used **PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17** on **Ubuntu 14.04**

First check the folder

```
#ls /etc/php5/mods-available/
json.ini  mcrypt.ini  mysqli.ini  mysql.ini  mysqlnd.ini  opcache.ini  pdo.ini  pdo_mysql.ini  readline.ini  xcache.ini
```

If it did not contain **mysqli.ini**, read other answer for installing it,

Open `php.ini` find **extension_dir**

In my case , I must set `extension_dir = /usr/lib/php5/20121212`

And restart apache2 : `/ect/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem after a long analysing procedure.
After properly testing my php installation with the command line features I found out that the php is working well and could work with the mysql database. Btw. you can run code-files with php code with the command   php -f filename.php
So I realized, it must something be wrong with the Apache.
I made a file with just the phpinfo() function inside.
Here I saw, that in the line
**Loaded Configuration File**
my config file was not loaded, instead there was mentioned (none).
Finally I found within the Apache configuration the entry

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>
```

But I've installed the PHP 7 and so the Apache could not load the php.ini file because there was no entry for that.
I added

```
<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>
```

and after restart Apache all works well.

These code blocks above I found in my httpd-xampp.conf file.  May it is somewhere else at your configuration.
In the same file I had changed before the settings for the php 7 as replacement for the php 5 version.

```
#
# PHP-Module setup
#
#LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
#LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

As you can see I have the xampp package installed but this problem was just on the Apache side.

Answer (score 0):

on **Debian 10**

```
apt install php-mysql

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

install
phpXX-extension by PHP.
In my FreeBSD's case:

```
pkg install php74-extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xampp and my problem was fixed once i rename:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

to

```
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

PS: Don't forget to restart apache after making this change!

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini :

```
extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.9/ext/"
```

Make sure the PHP version is correct.

Answer (score -1):

When I tried my PHP web app it was giving me the same error.

By googling I found out the MySQL plugin for the PHP server was missing with my installation. I am using Ubuntu, so when I tried MySQL plugin for PHP I found out 2 are there,

`php-mysql` and `php<version>-mysql`

I issued command - `php --version` in my terminal, I was having php7.4,

again I issued `apt install php7.4-mysql`

It worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you tried all answers above and are still out of luck, then do check if the version numbers of the packages installed on your system really match:

```
apache2-mod_php7-7.4.33-150200.3.46.2.x86_64
php7-mysql-7.4.33-150200.3.46.2.x86_64
```

Once I had to do a manual installation from a different repo, which lead to certain libs not getting loaded (though their config was OK and their .ini files were getting parsed).

You can also try using

```
php -S <server_ip>:8080
```

to launch a test server and see if your missing module (mysqli) loads there. If it shows up in phpinfo there (and doesn't in your regular configuration), then you at least know where to have a look at...

Answer (score -2):

This issue can be also caused by the .htaccess file misconfiguration.