# PHP unable to run MYSQLI functions on Amazon EC2 micro instance

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm just now implementing a PHP <-> MYSQL interface.  The instance seems to be reporting that the MYSQLI plugin is not installed, however, all other indications are contrary.

My Code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    $mysql = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'EulerPhpUser', '*********' );
    // more code
```

error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/euler/login.php on line 27

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.03
```

Here's the portion of my php.ini file

```
; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.max-links
mysqli.max_links = -1

; Default port number for mysqli_connect().  If unset, mysqli_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.default-port
mysqli.default_port = 3306

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.default-socket
mysqli.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.default-host
mysqli.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.default-user
mysqli.default_user =

; Default password for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysqli.default_pw")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.default-pw
mysqli.default_pw =

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect = Off
```

This is the only section of the phpifo() where my search for mysqli yielded results

```
Configure Command 
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-amazon-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-t1lib=/usr' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-mhash' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--libdir=/usr/lib64/php' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem'
```

Finally, one other thing to note.  I tried to run the following code, and the server returns a completely blank page back.  No errors, no nothing. As if php crashed without generating an error.  I'm not sure how to interpret that.

```
if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
     echo 'mysqli is installed';
}
```

I even got so frustrated that I tried some PDO, but then got error **Connection failed: could not find driver**

Comment: Did you enable the mysqli extensions in the php.ini?

Comment: The portion of my php.ini file which had "mysqli" in it is posted above.

Comment: I'd close this question if I could, but Stack Overflow doesn't seem interested in making their site intuitive or user friendly, so I have no motivation to put forth effort to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 12):

In AWS, I got this error and found that I needed to run "yum install php-mysqli". This is in addition to the mysql and php packages.

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed php 7.1, eg

```
sudo yum install php71
```

You will also need to install mysqli separately, eg

```
sudo yum install php71-mysqli
```

**Do not run**

```
sudo yum install php-mysqli
```

As this will install php 5

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Up to where I understand your PHP installation was compiled with `mysqli` support but the module is not enabled. Why? Because you specify that the only reference to `mysqli` in the `phpinfo()` is the `Configure Command`. Should it be enabled, a table like [image: this one]
should show up.

So, maybe, you simply didn't uncomment the extension line in your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

**Initial post:**

According to the [official docummentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php):

> To check whether the system is using a configuration file, try
>   retrieving the value of the cfg_file_path configuration setting. If
>   this is available, a configuration file is being used.

In other words, you could check if your php.ini file is being taken into account (it may be in a wrong path). Try:

```
<?php echo 'Configuration file (php.ini) path: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

Comment: output:  
Configuration file (php.ini) path: /etc/php.ini  
It's pointing there and I can confirm that's where the file is located.  
  
  
`$ cd /etc  
[ec2-user@* etc]$ ls | grep php  
php.d  
php.ini  
php-zts.d  
[ec2-user@ip-10-253-73-35 etc]$`  
  
wow.. what a confoundedly stupid way to have to "markdown" comments...  it says line breaks with two spaces at the end. nope

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I checked over the php.ini file, and indeed, there was no line: `extension=php_mysqli.dll`.  I added it in and restarted httpd, but to no avail.  The missing section of phpinfo() for MYSQLI did not appear.  I'm going to check over some other default php.ini files for differences.  In the meantime, you can see my info file [here](http://www.travishoward.net/info.php), and a copy of my php.ini file [here (with comments)](http://www.travishoward.net/php.ini.full.html) or [here (without)](http://www.travishoward.net/php.ini.html) Thank you for your continued assistance.

Comment: Try running `php -r 'dl("mysqli.so"); phpinfo();' | grep mysqli` to check if the module load normaly with `dl()` function.

Comment: As you are using Linux, change `extension=php_mysqli.dll` to `extension=mysqli.so`. In your php.ini you may want to uncomment `; extension_dir = "./"` and put the correct path to your extensions. Also, enable `enable_dl = On` to use the dl() function to test.

Comment: I believe I may have seriously corrupted my PHP or MYSQLI installation in my attempts to resolve the trouble.  As such, I've started a new AMI (Ubuntu Server 13) and MYSQLI seems to be working right out of the box. I thank you all for your time and effort, and definitely learned a few things.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this error on Amazon Linux upgrading PHP from 5.3 to 5.6.

There is no `php56-mysqli` package. There is `php56-mysqlnd`, which I had installed. `php-mysqli` was the 5.3 version [on AWS Linux].

The problem turned out to be that the installer left some PHP 5.3 pieces behind, notably `/usr/bin/php` (!).

To correct this problem, run:

```
$ alternatives --force --refresh php
```

Flag `--force` is needed to make `alternatives` overwrite files left where the links should have been.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum -y install php-mysqlnd
```

if mysqlnd installed, mysqli will use ^^

have nice day!!

in terminal check enable mysqli

```
php -r "phpinfo();"
```