# Class mysqli not found

Tags: php, mysqli

I have used `mysqli` to connect to the database in my application. It worked fine for a few days and suddenly it started showing the following error:

> Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found

The line I used to connect to the database is:

```
 $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'uname', 'password', 'scripts');
```

*Could you please tell me what might have gone wrong?*

Comment: use `phpinfo()` to verify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable mysqli extension in your php.ini

Just search for extension=php_mysqli.dll or somethig and remove the #

Comment: Did you restart apache yet? If not restart it.

Comment: uncommenting the ;extension=php_mysqli.dll in php.ini fixed this for me - changed
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
to
extension=php_mysqli.dll

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to have [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) installed before you can use it. Also you'll have to enable it (when installed) in your `php.ini` file.

You can test if you have it with this code:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'no mysqli :(';
} else {
    echo 'we gots it';
}
```

When you've done that, and there still is an error, please provide us with more details (OS, PHP version etc)

Comment: I have edited php.ini.. the same error is shown.PHP version:5.4.11

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Could you include the current loaded extensions from you `php.ini` in your question?