# mysqli doesn't work with apache, but works from PHP console

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, apache2

This PHP script:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $foo = new mysqli();
    var_dump($foo);
?>
```

gives this error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/xubuntu/Documents/www/quote_register/foo.php on line 5".
```

However, running this from the PHP console:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~/Documents/www/quote_register$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $foo = new mysqli();
php > var_dump($foo);
```

dumps a mysqli-object as expected.

Honestly, I'm quite stumped by this... Anyone got any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you see `mysqli` `in phpinfo()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found

Comment: Command-line PHP uses a different settings file. You need to install/enable Mysqli for the web interpreter as well.

Answer (score 0):

did you run the same php versions?

maybe a solution could be to check if cli and apache version have the same

1. php version
2. php ini-load
3. php mysqli config

to do this, just try phpinfo() on both and compare