# MySQLi is NOT missing

Tags: php, mysqli, xdebug, php-5.3

I am trying to write PHP that connects to a MySQL database. My debugger tells that class `mysqli` cannot be found. But my `phpinfo()` has `conf.d/mysqli.ini` on list of parsed `.ini`.

To debug this code I am using [Eclipse PDT](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt), with [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org). Why would the debugger not be able to find 'mysqli'??

NOTE: I am not sure if this is relevant, but this is configuration of the PHP executable:

```
PHP executable: /usr/bin/php5
Additional .ini:  /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Below is the actual error message from the console:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/RBDM_Project/WebContent/login.php on line 8

Call Stack:
    0.0099     333880   1. {main}() /var/www/RBDM_Project/WebContent/login.php:0
```

And the line 8 of the code:

```
 $db = new mysqli("URL","user","password","db");
```

UPDATE: I figured I might throw in a screenshot form phpinfo() 
[image]

Comment: can you show how you are connecting to the db?

Comment: Aren't class names case sensitive? Maybe it's just a simple error like that. Having a piece of code might help us spot the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you use the CLI version with your Eclipse and another php.ini?

Comment: Stony yes you are right, that was the default I think. I don't quite understand(YET) that .ini CLI etc. stuff So I left it as it is.

Comment: I tried to change SAPI I cannot even save changes with GCI, looks like I can only do CLI

Comment: I suppose "list of parsed .ini" is not exactly proof that the mysqli extension is being loaded.

Comment: Oh and in Linux, PHP has a separate config for Apache and when its ran standalone in shell (CLI).

Comment: Havenard, that makes sense I am running this on Ubuntu. So on that note I will run through my configuration to try using config for Apache

Comment: Ok I tried to use config form apache and the problem remains. I am starting to think that this might be problem with debuger instead

Comment: I have encountered this problem as well. When run from the command line, the script has no problem finding mysqli, however when run from within Eclipse with XDebug, it cannot find mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

These questions/recommendations might be better as a comment, but as a newbie to Stack Overflow I can't post comments.

1. Do you have multiple versions of PHP installed? I'm only vaguely familiar with the Eclipse PDT so I'm not sure how it invokes PHP. But if you have multiple versions installed on your system, you may want to check the output of a call to phpversion to make sure the proper version of PHP is being executed.
2. Did you compile PHP yourself? Does the configure options line in the phpinfo output show '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd'? It should since the screenshot you posted shows mysqli enabled, but at this point it couldn't hurt to check.
3. Last suggestions, which you may have already done, verify the libraries the extension depends on are installed and your configuration in php.ini. This is an old post which you may have already seen, but it has some details on that: *[Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811)*

Comment: strwils, you were almost there, but nonetheless very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were basically right, it turned out that because I installed mysqli after `libapache2-mod-php5`(I think that's what its called), I had to recompile `libapache2-mod-php5`. For some reason that did not happened when I installed additional php modules.

Then again I am not sure it that is supposed to be done by package manager, or do I need to do it myself each time.

Long story short I reinstalled `libapache2-mod-php5` and I got desired result .