# Mysqli not working at terminal lubuntu

Tags: php, linux, mysqli, ubuntu

Before this it works well.
After i trying messed up upgrade to php5.6 then downgrade again to 5.5 the mysqli not working at my terminal.

It return error message .

> "Fatal error: Class 'MySqli' not found"

I have try some of suggestion over stackoverflow but none of them working .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to install [MySqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php)

Here's the command you need.

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

After installation don't forget to stop and start or restart Apache

Additional Note :

To check whether you have mysqli in your bundle or not you can try that with this code

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'MySQLi, Not Installed';
} else {
    echo 'MySQLi Exists';
}
```

Comment: No, this one not working . Your answer same like other thread(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found) but it not working . That script will always return MySQLi, Not Installed at terminal but MySQLi Exists at web browser . I already tried this .

Comment: Without `mysqli_init` i fear how it could be possible

Comment: Your terminal and your browser shows different output ?? !!

Comment: yes . that's why my question not working at terminal .

Comment: Can you please run it in terminal to see whether both refers same `php.ini` by using this `php -i |grep "php.ini"` in terminal and `echo php_info()` from browser ??

Comment: Can you able to notice different paths of  `php.ini` loaded ?

Comment: I not sure because when i go to /usr/local/lib there no php.ini even inside php folder

Comment: Can you type this in terminal `find / -type f -name "php.ini"` to search all the php.ini in your machine ?

Comment: It return /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

both same still not working http://sitepreview.ourace.com/compareini.php?s=1&g=5526014488b1a5526014488b52

Comment: By enabling the extension `extension=mysqlnd.so` in both files it doesn't means that it is installed. Do you enabled it manually or what ??

Comment: I manage to fix this after remove php 5.3.xx . I tried to downgrade before . after complete remove follow this http://askubuntu.com/questions/569067/how-to-uninstall-both-packaged-and-manually-installed-versions-of-php it works again .

Comment: That's great to hear !