# Mysqli not found in Ratchet pusher class

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello Iam creating a chat with Ratchet. But in the pusher `onOpen` function i want it to access the database but when i put this line of code in my pusher class,

```
$connn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

i get the error below

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\mysqli' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fotoserver\src\MyApp\Chat.php on line 25
```

my pusher class is in namespace `MyApp` What is wrong? why cant i access the dababase ? Any help will be hightly appreciated

Comment: i think *mysqli* not configure in your server. this will help to you i hope  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found?rq=1

Comment: I actually checked and its installed

Comment: i am also having this problem