# MySQLi class not found in CPanel

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cpanel, web-hosting

I have made a website for my college. As long as I had been running it on localhost (using XAMPP) to run the php code and the databases, all was working fine. But when I deploy the site on server it gives the following error

Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/mietjmu/public_html/crie/index.php on line 55.

I also tried to search on the internet but all i was getting is that to open Easyapache from the WHM but was not able to find that option either. The server is being hosted by godaddy.com

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found

Comment: Sounds like you just need to install MySQLi.

Comment: i need to know how to do this in a cpanel account as i am having no option of doing so

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in the database code. It would be easier for someone to help you if you add the index.php file that gives this error, so we can figure out the error.

Comment: it should be in comment area .

Comment: But the code is working fine when i run it on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

check is mysql librery present or not :

```
    if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
      echo 'you dont have';
     } else {
      echo 'you have!';
     }
```

Comment: it is not present

Comment: If you are on `Ubuntu`, run:  `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`

Comment: i am hosting the site on godaddy and want to know how to do it in cpanel