# I am struggling to enable MySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to enable MySQLi, and it doesn't seem to be working. When I originally tested my code it came out with an error message that said "Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Login-system\sql\sql_import.php on 7". I looked online to see what it meant and released that I needed to enable MySQLi.

I have removed the comment on the extension=php_mysqli.dll line in the php.ini file, this was recommended to me on multiple sites. I still get the same error message.

I have added in the code I am using below;

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'The sloth19';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$password);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    die();
}

if ( !$mysqli->query('CREATE DATABASE accounts') ) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing database name in `mysqli` constructor. Checkout php site http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: you sure you have uncommented extension in right configuration file (specified in "Loaded Configuration File" of `phpinfo()`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found)

Comment: @PankajMakwana the DB name is optional

Answer (score 1):

In addition to uncommenting the `php_mysqli.dll` extension in `php.ini`, also uncomment the `extension_dir` directive in `php.ini` and specify your location:

In my case , I must set

```
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

and restart your apache24.

Comment: *"restart your apache"* <- probably the part OP was missing :)

Comment: Would the location I need to specify be for where I have my connection code saved?

Comment: This is not the connection path. Read [Where to find an extension?](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php#install.pecl.windows.find) for more details.