# MySQLi not found dockerized php

Tags: php, docker, mysqli, mysqlnd

I'm trying to dockerize my website. I've got Nginx and PHP up and running and it's working find except I can't connect to a db. When the page is loaded I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MySQLi' not found in /private/conn.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/index.php(2): require() #1 {main} thrown in /private/conn.php on line 8
```

My connection line on line 8 is:

```
$db = new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db", "$port");
```

Now this used to work fine on my old set up but since moving to a new one and installing php7.1.5 I can't get it running. Now, I haven't used the mysqlnd so this may be a misunderstanding on my part but the mysqlnd includes the mysqli driver.

Output of phpinfo:
[image: config]
[image: mysqlnd]

How can I get this running? Or should I be using a different driver now?

Comment: Can you show the Dockerfile? You need to enable extensions there, but it depends on what is your base image.

Comment: I'm using the php:fpm from here [https://hub.docker.com/_/php/](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)

Comment: Just out of curiosity...were you using docker for windows?

Comment: @Zuabi no it was on a Linux box

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to enable the php extension in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

There is no need to touch `php.ini`.

Comment: Some how it did not work for.  This is in my `Dockerfile` `FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli` It did not give any error either

Comment: This is the basic thing. He got from docker php official image.

Comment: Put where Id docker file?!?

Comment: @Volatil3 Need to run docker-compose up --build.

Answer (score 14):

i had similar issue with
**php:7-apache** image, which by default will not have mysqli installed
you can verify this inside the container

```
$ docker exec -it <phpcontainerid> bash
```

inside the docker container bash terminal

```
# docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

if mysqli is not installed which you will come to know from the output of above command

```
# docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

then i commited this change so the same image

```
$ docker commit -p <phpcontainerid> <new or same image name>
```

Comment: You helped me a lot, Abhishek. I didn't know that I can run docker-php-ext-install from container, then I lost much time running apt commandos trying to install in a traditional way. Thanks.

Comment: This is how i got it running with `php:7.4-apache` on Ubuntu. Interestingly, the `docker-php-ext-install mysqli` command in my Dockerfile "worked" in the output, but without solving the issue when running PHP. Can't understand it.

Answer (score 10):

> works for me:

inside php container:

```
docker-php-ext-install mysqli

apachectl restart
```

- docker images: mysql, php:7.2.30-apache

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/391

Comment: official php-apache docker does not include mysqli, if you really need mysqli, because you won't to change your code, this is the solution

Comment: This is the solution!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, fixed it by adding below line to dockercompose

`RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli`

And rebuild docker

`docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the MysqlI extension enabled in your php.ini.
If enabled, you should see a section `mysqli` in your phpinfo.

More info on enabling the extension can be found here: [Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found)

Comment: I added `extension=php_mysqli.dll` to my `php.ini` file but no change. Does it need to be installed? and if so - what is MySQLnd?

Comment: I think it's installed by default, but you have to restart apache first. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

**Confirm that your MySQL version should compatible with PHP version for docker**

*Detail*:-

First, ensure that in phpinfo page you should have mysqli installed information if not then.....
[image]

otherwise, install it and if you think you installed it in docker but not working

then Confirm that your MySQL version should compatible with PHP version for docker
like

first I was using this pair for docker

- php:7.4-apache & mysql:5.7 (but it was not working and showing error
  Class 'mysqli' not found)

after that I installed

- **php:7.2-apache & mysql:5.7** and **it works fine for me**