# PHP 7.4.1 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli

My question is just similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109173/php-7-2-1-uncaught-error-class-mysqli-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I am using PHP version 7.4.1 in Windows 7 [32bit].

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')){
        echo 'We don\t have mysqli'; 
    }
    else{
        echo'Yes';
    }
    mysqli_connect('localhost', "root", "", "akash");
?>
```

**It returns:**

> We don\t have mysqli
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefinedfunction mysqli_connect()

**What I have tried:**

As I have seen various answers on this problem and all the answers is simply based on the *php.inf*  file but in my php directory there is no file of this name and  so after looking on how to install this I couldn't really find a way, after visiting http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php, I scrolled down to find the "PHP 5.3.0 and newer" section where it says I wouldn't need to worry about installing it.

Comment: Run the `phpinfo();` function and display that output to see if mysqli is loaded, or alternatively on the command line do `php -i | grep mysqli`. If it is not, then look in the output of those commands for the path to the php.ini file so you can enable it.

Comment: How do you run the php? Is it called from the command line? Or it runs as a part of some server (e.g. Apache)?

Comment: @AterLux  using this command in my cmd : php -S localhost:8080

Comment: @Jeremy Harris  please  execuse my ignorance, when i  run phpinfo()  i got PHP Version 7.4.1 tables but i unable to understand what to do next

Comment: I meant to write that function in your code (comment that other stuff) and run it. Then in your browser use the "Find" function to search for "mysqli" and also for "php.ini". The latter will show you the full path to the config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to have a `php.ini` somewhere.

Usually in the directory with php you have two files `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` - they are examples of `php.ini` with some recommended settings.

1. Copy `php.ini-development` into `php.ini` and place it somewhere.
2. Find the line

```
;extension=mysqli
```

and uncomment it (remove the semicolon from the beggining)

3. Run your server. If `php.ini` is placed not where `php.exe` is, then pass the path to it  in the command line after `-c` option:

```
D:\path\to\php\php.exe -S localhost:8080 -c D:\path\to\ini\file\php.ini ...
```

Comment: sir i already tried this but i am uncommiting ;extension=mysqli
 and other various types of extension but this not helps me or i forgot to restart my server, but your answer helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you host the server yourself, in the **php.ini** file remove the semicolon in front of the extension **extension=php_mysqli.dll**