# Problems arise when linking php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

Looking at the error through the display

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in D:\Apache24\htdocs\mysqltest.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Apache24\htdocs\mysqltest.php on line 10

is displayed, and the Chrome console window shows

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in D:\Apache24\htdocs\mysqltest.php:10
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in **D:\Apache24\htdocs\mysqltest.php** on line **10**

I will also attach the .php code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $user = "root";
    $pass = "1234";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbdb = "mysql";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "It works, Connected successfully";

?>
```

I've been crying for two days. Please solve it.

I was told that it was a problem that mysql could not receive the php extension, so I tried to solve it on my own, but even if I modified php.ini, modified the directory path, changed to pdo, or reinstalled mysql, it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Create a page that contains `<?php`, `phpinfo();` and `?>` and execute that.  That will tell you the exact state of all of your extensions.  Where did you get your copy of PHP from?  Did you build it?

Comment: `changed to pdo` would not produce that same error. Did you receive the same error? Do you have pdo/mysqli enabled?

Comment: A copy of PHP was obtained for testing purposes through Googling. Looking at phpinfo, both are enabled.

Comment: When checking phpinfo you ran it through the same portal you are viewing the page on? e.g. added `phpinfo()` into `mysqltest.php` or made a new script in same dir and executed in browser as well? Does the PHP version sent in the HTTP header match the PHP version in phpinfo output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/how-to-solve-fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found)